# how can i use jasypt for spring.datasource.password=${db.password:abcd}

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I am using spring-boot and I have below the property for db connection.
I want to use jasypt for below 
`spring.datasource.password=${db.password:abcd}` property

I tried `spring.datasource.password=${db.password:ENC(<encypted-val>)}` property

But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
:ENC(<encypted-val>)
```

will only work in application.properties. Put this value in a variable in properties file and use that variable in your class.
Jasypt will decrypt only the values in proeprties file

Comment: Do we need to create Datasource? I want to avoid creating datasource as I am just autowiring my JDBCTemplate.